# Vim formarts postgres wrong

Tags: formatting

I use vims autoformat feature a lot. But it doesn't work properly for postgres

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid INT, foosubid INT, fooname TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2, 'three');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 5, 'six');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo() RETURNS SETOF foo AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
r foo%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo
        WHERE fooid > 0
        LOOP
            
            RETURN NEXT r; 
        END LOOP; --should indent here
        RETURN;
    END -- and here
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

The indents don't work properly for loops like this one. Is there a plugin that fixes this? The filetype is recognized as sql